# Query a table then stream results to socket.io with knex and postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sockets, socket.io, knex.js

I want to query a table and write the contents to a socket as they come in, for a larger query. [I was reading the documentation for streams](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Streams). I was trying to implement this with socket.io. Below is my example of a `/users` route, where `app` is an instance of `express` and `io` is a `socket.io` instance.

```
module.exports = function (app, io) {
  app.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    const limit = req.queryParams.limit || 100;
    const stream = req.db.select('*').from('users').limit(limit).stream();
    req.on('close', stream.close.bind(stream));  // manually close on request cancel
    // how can you stream to the socket?
    // how do you know when the amount is reached to end the response?
  });
}
```

What I am wondering is; *how can I stream the results from this query into the io socket*? I want to essentially emit an `added` event whenever a result is found, using the tablename, id, and found entry as arguments.

Comment: Your data source or the type of data is irrelevant to the socket.io. So effectively you are asking - how to stream data with socket.io? Have you even tried?

Comment: I'm specifically asking, **using the streaming interface with knex** how to stream. I have the linked documentation from knex

Comment: knex exposes a generic stream protocol, which can work with socket.io in a generic way. It will help you better if you post the exact issue you were having trying to stream the data into socket.io.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how can you stream to the socket?

You can access the streamed DB rows by listening for the `data` event from the knex stream and passing the data along to socket.io via `io.emit`.

> how do you know when the amount is reached to end the response?

The stream will emit an `end` event.

You know the stream is done when the `end` event fires, but since you are accepting requests on an HTTP channel but responding over a separate web socket channel, you can send the HTTP response to `res` right away without waiting for the DB query results if you like (`res.send()`).

```
 module.exports = function (app, io) {
  app.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    const limit = req.queryParams.limit || 100;
    const stream = req.db.select('*').from('users').limit(limit).stream();
    stream.on('data', function (row) {
      io.emit('user', row)
    })
    .on('error', function (error) {
      io.emit('error', error.message)
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      io.emit('end')
    })
    req.on('close', stream.close.bind(stream));  // manually close on request cancel
    // how can you stream to the socket?
    // how do you know when the amount is reached to end the response?
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you know that these events are emitted, though? Is there some way to tell? I didn't see it in the docs

Comment: This is precisely the generic way of doing it, as I was trying to explain just earlier :) And the right way, of course.

Comment: yes, but how would you _know_ these events would happen? I thought that that looked right when I wrote it. Were you saying that it implements the same methods and events as the `net.Socket` class?

Comment: Those are the standard stream events, and even if the stream is empty, event `end` will happen always. Event `close` though depends on the stream implementation.

Comment: [Th node core API docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html) define the standard APIs for both readable and writable streams. These APIs include the event names and arguments as well as the methods on stream instances themselves, and all the associated semantics, guarantees, warnings, etc. Anything that states it is a node.js stream should conform to this API. Thus they are broadly interoperable.